# Inactive Controls on ViewController despite working referencing outlets

Tags: events, uiview, uiviewcontroller, controls, iboutlet

I was wondering if anyone else has seen this.  I would include a screen shot but it would be unilluminating, showing all the referencing outlets and event handlers hooked up exactly as they should be, the same thing that was working perfectly before I made some changes.  I had a very simple UIView with some text and a single control which I edited to have more controls, and after building none of them worked.  The IBOutlet variables all worked, I was able to set text and control states on viewWillLoad, but all control were inactive.  They were enabled, allowing user interaction, I even tried setting their enabled properties in code.  Dead.

Finally I created a new view, copied and pasted the subviews into it, hooked up the event handlers and referencing outlets, and it worked right away.

Does anyone have any insights to share on this?  I tried cleaning the project, rebooting the machine, the whole gamut.  OK, "the nib must have been corrupt," but why?

Thanks for any insights.